# Advanced Javascript Regex Class?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have found the below Javascript recently, and (believe) I understand its operation, but cannot figure out (what appears) to be a ¿regex string class? ("/\W/.test")

```
   function AlphaNumericStringCheck(text) 
   {
       if (/\W/.test(text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""))) return false;
       return true;
   }
```

Can someone put a name to this technique, so I can research it more?

Comment: `/\W/` is a regular expression literal. Regular expressions have methods you can invoke. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is--are you asking about the immediate regex expressions? What do you mean by "regex string class"? It's a regex, not a string.

Comment: Are you referring to the method test() on the content between slashes? If so that would be the RegExp object in JavaScript. It is merely a consolidated syntax for regular expressions in JS. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: @Felix Kling - Thanks. I was aware of the two ways of invoking a regex object in that article, but have never seen this way of invoking a Regular Expression

Comment: @Dave Newton - Sorry, it was my way of describing what looked to me to be a /\W/ object (my mistake on classname) and test function being called, but thought you couldn't start a object name with anything but a alphanumeric character

Comment: @Adam Presley - Thanks for your response, but hope the above answers your clarifications

Comment: @user66001 You're not starting an object name, you're creating an object using JS's immediate regex syntactic sugar. It's an anonymous object with no name, the same as `5` is an object. You can't name a variable starting with an alphanumeric, it must be a letter, underscore, dollar sign, etc--you can't start a variable name with, say, a number.

Comment: @user66001: It might help if you know that you can do the same with other literals, such as `[1,2,3].join()`, `"foo,bar".split(',')`, which are just array and string literals. It does not always work if the expression is ambiguous, like `5.toFixed()` does not work, but `5.3.toFixed()` or `(5).toFixed()` do.

Comment: @Felix Kling - Great to know. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/\W/` in your source code is a [regular expression literal](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.5) ([MDC link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), as MDC is about 18X clearer than the specification). Just as with a string literal ("foo"), a regular expression literal is a way of writing regular expressions in the code. The `/` characters in a regular expression literal are analogous to the quote characters in a string literal. In a string literal, what's inside the quotes is the content of the string; in a regular expression literal, what's inside the `/` characters is the regular expression. (There can also be flags following the ending `/`.)

So this:

```
var rex = /\W/;
```

...creates a regular expression object for the regular expression `\W` (match one word character). It's (essentially) equivalent to:

```
var rex = new RegExp("\\W");
```

Note that in the long form, I had to escape the backslash in the string, since backslashes are special in string literals. This is one of the reasons we have regular expression literals: Because it gets very confusing, very quickly, when you have to escape all of your backslashes (backslashes being a significant part of many regular expressions).

Regular expressions are objects, which have properties with functions attached to them (effectively, methods, although JavaScript doesn't technically have *methods* per se). So `/\W/.test(...)` calls the `test` function on the regular expression object defined by the literal `/\W/`.

Comment: Thanks T.H Crowder. "So /\W/.test(...) calls the test function on the regular expression object defined by the literal /\W/" is the sort of answer I was looking for. have not seen this form before, and obviously don't have a full understanding of what can be done with a functions & objects in JS. Side note - Would be good if the MDC document would have listed this form as an example!

Comment: @user66001: Glad that helped! Re the MDC doc: It has several examples of literals, and even has this example buried in it: "`/\d+(?!\.)/.exec("3.141")` matches `141` but not `3.141`."

Comment: So it does, though I didn't read about regex, as I already am comfortable with that :(

Answer (score 0):

`\W` is a shortcut (shorthand character classes or extensions) for word. Just like `\d` for digits and `\s` for whitespace and new lines. It depends on the implementation of the regex you're using.

This literals are replaced by full expression before compiled. `\d` turns into `[0-9]` and `\W` probably turns into `[0-9a-Z][0-9a-Z]*` or similar. They are designed to make your expressions more readable.

You can see some more of them here: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#special

Comment: Thanks Guax. Should have probably mentioned I am very familiar with RegEx, and the example regex was not the issue, just the /\W/ object.